# Installation of package.json

Tags: php, linux, shell, github, composer-php

i am unable to install this library from GitHub. [Minishlink/web-push]

I have Laravel 5 installed on my server, I want to install this in the Laravel directory (project). And will use the library via custom PHP.

I am facing below issues:

1. When I run `composer require minishlink/web-push`, I get below error:[image]
2. When I run `composer require mdanter/eec`, I get below error[image]
3. When I run `composer require pargonie/rndom_compat`, I get below error[image]

Here is the `composer.json` file (*I have not included the web-push file here as I am using the require command via putty, [**Please correct me if I'm wrong**]*)

```json
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.1.*",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~4.0",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "~2.0.0",
        "aloha/twilio": "^2.0",
        "laravel/socialite": "2.0.*",
        "ixudra/curl": "6.*",
        "laracasts/utilities": "^2.1"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1",
        "laracasts/utilities": "~2.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "pre-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

Comment: Please avoid pasting textual content as images. Images are hard to read, they're not searchable, and they're not accessible. Instead, copy the text directly into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the same type of issue as [#17](https://github.com/Minishlink/web-push/issues/17). It's not related to Minishlink/web-push. One of your dependancies is stuck in the past with paragonie/random_compat v1.1.5. You should check which one and ask the owner to update the composer.json. To fix this temporarily, in your composer.json, on your **dev machine** put:

```
"paragonie/random_compat": "dev-master as 1.1.5",
"minishlink/web-push": "^1.1"
```